# Show a polynomial is reducible to linear terms - check my answer

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

I have an exam tomorrow in linear algebra, and I want to make sure I answered this question correctly.

Let $p \in \mathbb R[x], z \in \mathbb{C}$.

We are given if $Im(z)>0$ then $p(z)\neq0$

Show that it is possible to reduce $p$ to linear terms in $\mathbb R[x]$

My solution:

We know that every polynomial of $n$th degree has $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$. However, we know that if $b>0$ then $a+bi$is not a root of $p$.

if $a+bi$ is not a root of $p$ then $a-bi$ is not a root of $p$ either because it is it's conjugate.

That mean's all the roots of $p$ are of the form$a+0i=a \in \mathbb{R}$, so $p$ has $n$ roots in $\mathbb{R}$ and so it is reducible to linear terms in $\mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: "\neq" is !=, for the record.

Comment: this seem to be fine for me.. let some one else confirm it....

Comment: Yes, this is correct.